# Are there Atmel and PIC libraries for Eagle?

Tags: eaglecad, atmel, library

I am using CadSoft's Eagle library with added libraries from Adafruit. However, I still see an overwhelming lack of modern Atmel products in the component list.

I'm relatively new to Eagle so I haven't the expertise to add my own components and I've searched and added some Atmel libraries from CadSoft's user library repository. This still hasn't helped.

So my question is, where can I find a fairly complete Atmel (and PIC) library for Eagle? Of course Atmel themselves are no help since articles found during a Google search of their site state they don't produce libraries for 3rd party software packages.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: It really isn't that hard to use Eagle's library tool to create custom parts. Read the manual and dive in!

Comment: @DaveTweed Alright, due to lack of existing I guess that's my only option. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The answer to your question is really not the answer you want to hear.

You could use a search engine to search for user generated EAGLE CAD files for Atmel chips but you may receive files that are poorly designed or old. Unless the files are from a co-worker or a capable individual that I know: I wouldn't trust other files.

It's usually always best to generate your own library so you ensure your parts comply with the device's datasheet. Creating your own parts for EAGLE is a good skill to learn, albeit a tedious one at times.

I found this 2 part video series by Hackaday very helpful when I started getting into EAGLE:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irE4oHB5fSc

There's so many other guides easily searchable online.

Comment: @user46884 Nick Williams is right. After learning to make Eagle parts, I even went back an remade some footprints and symbols I had previously taken from public libraries. It's gotten to the point that I _only_ use my own library. That way, I know what I'm getting, and can revision/update the designs as I need to. And, you know what? It turns out to be pretty easy! I can build a part faster than I can find and verify an online source.

Comment: Cool, well I guess the manual is my next port of call. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you need to learn to make your own parts.

However, while I do make all my own part, I let other people use them.  Install the Eagle Tools release from http://www.embedinc.com/pic/dload.htm and look around in the eagle --> lib directory within the software installation directory.  The pic.lbr library contains a bunch of Microchip PICs.